# Difference between casting ifstream to bool and using ifstream::is_open()

Tags: c++, casting, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Maybe a dummy question, but I need a clear answer to it. Is there any difference at all in the return of any of those functions

```
int FileExists(const std::string& filename)
{
  ifstream file(filename.c_str());
  return !!file;
}

int FileExists(const std::string& filename)
{
  ifstream file(filename.c_str());
  return file.is_open();
}
```

So in other words, my question is: does casting the `fstream` to `bool` give exactly the same result as `fstream::is_open()`?

Comment: As a side note, if you were to make those function return a `bool` (instead of `int`), you probably wouldn't need the `!!` operators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. `is_open` checks only whether there is an associated file, while a cast to `bool` also checks whether the file is ready for I/O operations (e.g. the stream is in a good state) (since C++11).

#### [`is_open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open)

> Checks if the file stream has an associated file.

#### [`std::basic_ios::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

> Returns true if the stream has no errors occurred and is ready of I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, checking whether a file exists should be done using fstream::is_open(), right?

Comment: @SamerAfach: Both methods are feasible ways to check whether the file exists. However, only the latter is correct if you want to additionally check whether the stream is in a good state. Stick to the one you like most.

Comment: Actually I don't care if the file is in a good state for I/O. I just want to know whether the file exists. The file could even be not accessible for user permissions stuff, but yet it exists. Which means fstream::is_open() is the safe option in this case, right?

Comment: @Samer - No, if the file is not accessible, the `open` is also likely to fail.

Comment: @Bo Persson Then I don't really see the difference. Can you please give an example where fstream::is_open() will give true and the cast will give false?

Comment: @SamerAfach: `ifstream file("test.txt"); int i; file >> i;`. If `test.txt` exists, is empty and could be opened, `file.is_open()` is true, but the extraction of an integer failed and `!!file` is false. Note that a false `is_open` _always_ implies `!!file` false.